# function generator javascript

Tags: javascript, generator

I need to make a function generator that iterates over an infinite sequence, like the fibonacci sequence. It should return the next value in the sequence when called. I am given a function prototype:

```
function genfib() {
  return function fib() {
  }
}
```

it should be used like this:

```
var fib = genfib();
fib(); // -> returns 0
fib(); // -> returns 1
fib(); // -> returns 1
fib(); // -> returns 2
```

I am confused about what is executing every time I call `fib()`. I tried to do something like

```
function genfib() {
  var count = 1;
  if (count === 1) {
    count++;
    yield 0;
  }
  else if (count === 2) {
    count++;
    yield 1;
  }
  var a = 0;
  var b = 1;
  return function fib() {
    while(1) {
      count = a + b;
      a = b;
      b = count;
      yield count;
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not working. I don't know how to set it up to run the `if/else` for the first two numbers in the `fib` sequence and then run the `while` loop once for each subsequent call.

Comment: Do you  know what `yield` does?

Comment: i think it's kind of like a return that only pauses a function instead of terminating it after returning a value

Comment: If this is an assignment/homework (from "*I am given a function prototype*"), then it looks like you are supposed to learn about closures. Not write generators with `yield`.

Comment: If our answers have been helpful to you, please mark one one of the answers as correct.

Comment: @Bergi this is not homework. i'm doing exercises on codewars to get better with javascript. there is no information about a desired approach other than the given method stub and the term "function generator" in the description

Comment: @user137717: Much the same :) But yes, that method stub is a definitive hint at using a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask me, `yield` has no place in this function, just some clever use of JavaScript [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

You had the right idea in the beginning - you do need a function that returns a function. Outside of the inner function have a couple variables - one for the old, one for the next. Inside the function, all you have to do is calculate the new `next` value, and then set `old` to the `next`'s previous value. To switch their values, you'll need a placeholder variable.

```js
function genfib() {
  var next = 1
  var old = 0
  return function fib() {
    var newNext= next + old
    old = next
    next = newNext
    return next
  }
}

var fib = genfib()

var result = []

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
  result.push( fib() )

document.body.innerHTML = result.join()
```

Of course, this doesn't account for the the first function call, which is a special case (1 should be returned twice.) But I'll leave that to you to figure out :-)

Comment: how is the state of fib preserved between calls? Why doesn't all that information get deleted when the function returns?

Comment: JS is a funky language if you come from a Java background. It'll take some time, but you have to grasp JS closure that I linked to.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use ES6 generators and `yield`, then here's the approach:

```
function *fibonacci() {
    var [prev, current] = [0, 1];

    while (true) {
        [prev, current] = [current, current+prev];
        yield current;
    }
}
```

One way to iterate over the results is with a `for-of` loop:

```
for (var v of fibonacci()) {
    console.log(v);
    if (v > 100) break;
}
```

Note that the destructuring assignment `var [prev, current] =` is supported in FF and Traceur but not in Chrome or node at present. If necessary rewrite it as:

```
function *fibonacci() {
    var prev = 0, current = 1, oldprev;

    while (true) {
        oldprev = prev;
        prev = current;
        yield current += oldprev;
    }
}
```

If you want the semantics of the function prototype you were given, then:

```
function genfib() {
    var iterator = fibonacci();
    return function fib() {
        return iterator.next().value;
    };
}
```

Comment: "var [prev, current]" - does that actually work? Since when? I don't think it's in ES5, and Chrome doesn't support ES6 yet (without a flag)

Comment: This is a really cool answer - just don't feel like switching browsers or firing up a server to run it :)

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, the OP will look like such a ninja turning this in.

Answer (score 1):

```
function* fib(num) {
  var a = num, b = a + 1, c = a;

  while (true) {
    yield a;
    c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c + b;
  }
}

var it = fib(0);
console.log(it.next().value); // 0
console.log(it.next().value); // 1
console.log(it.next().value); // 1
console.log(it.next().value); // 2
console.log(it.next().value); // 3
console.log(it.next().value); // 5
console.log(it.next().value); // 8
console.log(it.next().value); // 13
```

For a high level overview on how to use generators, [checkout this post](http://chrisbuttery.com/articles/synchronous-asynchronous-javascript-with-es6-generators/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function* fibonacci(){
  var fn1 = 1;
  var fn2 = 1;
  while (true){  
    var current = fn2;
    fn2 = fn1;
    fn1 = fn1 + current;
    var reset = yield current;
    if (reset){
        fn1 = 1;
        fn2 = 1;
    }
  }
}

var sequence = fibonacci();
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 3
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 5
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 8
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 13
console.log(sequence.next(true).value); // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 3
```